# Re-number disjoint sections of an array, by order of appearance

Tags: python, numpy

Consider an array of contiguous "sections":

```py
x = np.asarray([
   1, 1, 1, 1,
   9, 9, 9,
   3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
   5, 5, 5,
])
```

I don't care about the actual values in the array. I only care that they demarcate disjoint sections of the array. I would like to renumber them so that the first section is all `0`, the second second is all `1`, and so on:

```py
desired = np.asarray([
   0, 0, 0, 0,
   1, 1, 1,
   2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
   3, 3, 3,
])
```

What is an elegant way to perform this operation? I don't expect there to be a single best answer, but I think this question could provide interesting opportunities to show off applications of various Numpy and other Python features.

Assume for the sake of this question that the array is 1-dimensional and non-empty.

Comment: Could you have two sections with the same value, like two sections of 9s for instance?

Comment: @RoySmart in the real-world case I happened to have in mind, yes. But I think answers that handle the case where values cannot repeat might also be interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining `np.cumsum` with `np.diff` allows you to do this.

```py
a = np.cumsum(np.diff(x, prepend=x[0]) != 0)
```

Comment: Much tidier than my version! This is probably as good as it gets, although it might be fun if someone has another idea.

Comment: I posted this and then realized you had developed almost the same implementation!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a naïve but linear-time implementation using `nditer`:

```py
def renumber(arr):
    assert arr.ndim == 1

    val_prev = None  # Arbitrary placeholder
    section_number = 0
    result = np.empty_like(arr, dtype=int)
    with np.nditer(
        [arr, result],
        flags=['c_index'],
        op_flags=[['readonly'], ['writeonly']]
    ) as it:
        for val_curr, res in it:
            if it.index > 0 and val_curr != val_prev:
                section_number += 1
            res[...] = section_number
            val_prev = val_curr
    return result
```

There are certainly fancier ways to do this, but this implementation should serve as a sensible baseline:

```py
x = np.asarray([1, 1, 1, 1, 9, 9, 9, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5])
desired = array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3])
np.testing.assert_array_equal(renumber(x), desired)
```

Comment: My experience is that `nditer` doesn't help performance.  A zipped iteration is probably just as fast and easier to set up.

Comment: @hpaulj That's been my experience as well, but it's an interesting feature in Numpy!

Answer (score 0):

*Note: There is a nicer equivalent of this in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75552057/2954547).*

My [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75551992/2954547) essentially consists of comparing every value to the value before it, and incrementing a counter whenever that happens. This can be implemented in vectorized fashion by taking advantage of the fact that boolean `True` corresponds to integer `1`, and `False` corresponds to `0`.

```py
def renumber(arr):
    assert x.ndim == 1
    return np.cumsum(np.insert(x[1:] != x[:-1], 0, x[0] != x[1]))

x = np.asarray([1, 1, 1, 1, 9, 9, 9, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5])
desired = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3])
np.testing.assert_array_equal(renumber(x), desired)
```

Note that this is a little clunky due to the need to `np.insert` the first value. I would be very interested to know if there is a more elegant way to achieve this.